# Serving static assets via flatironjs

Tags: node.js, flatiron.js

Is there a built-in way for serving static assets (images/css/js) via flatironjs? Or do we need to write custom routes to do this? Couldn't find any examples for any built-in way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Union](https://github.com/flatiron/union) supports connect middleware so just add `require("connect").static` to the middleware stack

Answer (score 4):

flatiron now has a [plugin for static file serving](https://github.com/flatiron/flatiron/blob/master/lib/flatiron/plugins/static.js).

```
app.use(flatiron.plugins.static, { root: __dirname });
```

Example at: [flatiron/examples/static-app/app.js](https://github.com/flatiron/flatiron/blob/master/examples/static-app/app.js)

Comment: It does work, however is very ill-documented. I'm not sure what `root` option is for, because by default it will look for assets in `/app/assets/`. To change that, you use `dir` instead.